# Statistics of Gaussian Random Walk Passed Through the Heaviside Function

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, random-walk, error-function, step-function

Let

$$D=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}H\left(\xi_{n}-1\right),$$

such that $\xi$ denotes a Gaussian random walk with mean $\mu$ and $\sigma$, passed through the Heaviside function

$$H(x-1)=\begin{cases}
1, & x>1\\
0, & x\leq1.
\end{cases}$$

Can any statements be made about the family of distributions $H(\xi_n-1)$ belongs to, or its mean and variance? Any help would be much appreciated. **Please see answer to this question below where a new question is posed.**

**Realisation of Random Walk (for $N=1000$)**

Red line $D$, black line is $\xi_n$ (with $\mu=1$ and $\sigma=0.16$), and purple line is $H(\xi_n-1)$.

[image: Realisation of Random Walk]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For positive $\sigma$,

$$
\begin{split}
D&=\mathbb{E}\left[H\left(\xi_{n}-1\right)\right],\\&=\mathbb{P}\left(\xi_{n}\geq1\right),\\&\sim\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\ell-\mu}{\sigma}\right)^{2}\right)d\ell,\\&\sim\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right).
\end{split}$$

The $\sim$ is used to denote asymptotic equivalence. So, for infinite $n$ the relation holds since $$\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)=\mathbb{E}\left[\mathbb{P}\left(\xi_{n}\geq1\right)\right].$$
My question may be updated to *what is the error term for the approximation*? So, can $g(N)$ be found in
$$\mathbb{P}\left(\xi_{n}\geq1\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{1-\mu}{\sigma\sqrt{2}}\right)\right)+\mathcal{O}(g(N))?$$